# my gitlab build on digital-ocean cannot send mail to new user

Tags: smtp, gitlab, digital-ocean

i tried to configure SMTP in my Gitlab-Instance (following [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/smtp.md) guideline). but dont get it working.

> gitlab.rb

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = "admin@example.com"
gitlab_rails['gitlab_support_email'] = "admin@example.com"
#nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
#nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.crt"
#nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.key"

gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = 'smtp.exmail.qq.com'
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = 'admin@example.com'
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = 'has been removed'
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = 'smtp.qq.com'
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = :plain
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
```

> production.log

```
Sent mail to i@example.com (8017.5ms)
```

> mail.log

```
May  9 09:02:14 nday postfix/smtp[27203]: B16EF12019C: to=<i@example.com>, relay=none, delay=1049, delays=1017/0.04/32/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=mxbiz2.qq.com type=AAAA: Host not found, try again)s
May  9 09:02:14 nday postfix/smtp[27202]: 40274120CA7: to=<i@example.com>, relay=none, delay=988, delays=955/0.04/32/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=mxbiz2.qq.com type=AAAA: Host not found, try again)
```

BTW:I have changed the DNS and refresh. `mail.log` haven't logged my operation. It's old log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your account new on Digital Ocean?

If yes, you need to ask them to unlock sendmail functionality.

This unlock is by account, not by droplet.
You will can use sendmail in all others droplets created by you after this unlock.

Comment: If you like, please, mark this post as answer. Thanks. ;)